# Tomcat SSL Certificate Mismatched Address

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, virtualhost, tomcat8

In tomcat 8  we have 2  applications running in 2 virtual host

```
App 1 URL  https://ga1.mydomain.com

App 2 URL  https://ga2.mydomain.com
```

I have 2 SSL certificate in pxf format for each domain . I imported both pfx file into a JKS under different alias (ga1server, ga2server)

Tomcat starts and I am able to access https://ga1.mydomain.com thru HTTPs but when I try accessing the https://ga2.mydomain.com ,  I get Address Mismatched error

if I import ga2 domain certificate first and the other second in JKS, then https://ga2.mydomain.com works and https://ga1.mydomain.com throws mismatched error

How to solve this issue.

Comment: try to configure FQDNs for both domains, and check

Comment: i am using FQDNs while accessing the application

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20287941/4483015 where it is indicated this may not be possible natively in Tomcat 8. You can try terminating SSL at a point in front of Tomcat as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40853382/4483015